# Change cell background colour for highest value for each group

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have conditional formatting for column C where the cell background colour turn red for highest value in column B. I have column A with dropdown to select Groups(Groups 1 - 6). How to make colour turn red in column C to show only for one highest values in column B for each particular group in column A. New rows are inserted and deleted and cell colour in column C needs to change. Please suggest and advise on a solution.

Please see screenshot

[image]

AMENDED :

I have a command button to insert a new row and copy/paste to new row. All new rows are copied below. First row is no.15.

Code for that is below:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect "*****" 
lrow = Selection.Row()
Rows(lrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Rows(lrow + 1).Select
Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown
On Error Resume Next
ActiveCell.Offset.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlConstants).ClearContents
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Protect "*****", True, True
```

When a new row is added and when the row has no value, the problem begins.

All conditional formatting for existing rows above/below and for new row - everything disappears. Cannot see any cell background colour for the sheet.

When I delete the newly added blank row, then conditional formatting comes back to life and cell colours are back. Problem is only when I click on command button to add or insert a new row.

Answer (score 1):

In conditional formatting choose rule type 'Use formula...', enter following formula:

```
=B1=LARGE(($B$1:$B$7)*(A1=$A$1:$A$7);1)
```

(change ranges according to your needs), select the format you want, in the 'Applies to' field select range to which format will be applied.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but does not seem to work. Column A contains text 'Group 1 or Group2' from drop down selection from Data Validation menu list. Column B has values like 2 or 5. Column C needs to change cell colour to highlight the highest value of Column B in each group in column A.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Perhaps, you may need to replace the semicolon with a comma in my formula.

Comment: I have edited my question and added teh code i used for adding new row and the issue with it. Hopefully it is more clear now.